# Binding the Height of a Control to a unit specific measurement

Tags: wpf, binding, height, units-of-measurement

I am aware that in WPF you can specify the Height of a Control in different units.

For example:

```
<Setter Property="Height" Value="0.35cm"></Setter>
```

I want to bind the Height of a Control to a property in my ViewModel. How do I specify that the height is in centimeters when using a binding? I have tried to set the Height property in the ViewModel to a String and append "cm" behind the height measurement:

The ViewModel is created in XAML as follows:

```
<local:HeadingViewModel Height="0.35cm"></local:HeadingViewModel>
```

The Height of the Control is set via a binding in the style:

```
<Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Height, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"></Setter>
```

This sets the height, but it is not in centimeters. It seems to be set in the default units of WPF. Nothing happens when I change the height from "0.35cm" to "0.35in". It seems to stay in the default unit of WPF.

How can I set the Height property of a Control via Binding in a different measurement unit than the default unit?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a concept of binding using different units in WPF - all there is, is a `TypeConverter` - `LengthConverter` - which converts a string as provided by XAML into a `double`. Depending on the units you enter, it multiplies the result by a certain factor.

So if you want to bind to a double, you have to make sure you convert that double in code to WPF's units of 1/94th of an inch. Or you could make an `IValueConverter` to do it for you.

If you want to bind to a string, you could write an `IValueConverter` and call `LengthConverter` from within.